# Can I remove the Y-axis counter on chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

I have a chart.js graph that looks like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is remove this counter of the y-axis:

[image]

I read through the documentation and searched for it here on Stack Overflow, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the ticks display to false in the options object like this:

```
options: {
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      display: false
    }
  }]
}
}
```

Will give this result:
[image]

You can also use the callback to return an ampty string as tick which as side effect also removes the horizontal grid lines like this

```
options: {
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      callback: () => ('')
    }
  }]
}
}
```

result:
[image]